# Inscriptions on a 16th century 3-dimensional permutahedron sundial?

Tags: mathematics

Does anyone know what the inscriptions, written presumably in Latin, are on this 3-D permutahedron sundial by Stefano Buonsignori (16th century) in the Medici collection presented by [Museo Galileo](http://brunelleschi.imss.fi.it/museum/esim.asp?c=403055)?

[image: Sundial]

Added Mar. 9, 2024:

The refined Euler characteristic polynomials / refined, signed, face polynomials of the permutahedra / permutohedra are the coefficients of the multiplicative inverse, or reciprocal, of a Taylor series with constant term unity (see [OEIS A133314](https://oeis.org/A133314)).
The 3-dimensional permutohedron is one of the 13 Archimedean solids--[the truncated octahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_octahedron). Here's some history on illustrations of these solids from a Wikipedia post on the truncated icosahedron:

> The truncated icosahedron was known to Archimedes, who classified the 13 Archimedean solids in a lost work. All we know of his work on these shapes comes from Pappus of Alexandria, who merely lists the numbers of faces for each: 12 pentagons and 20 hexagons, in the case of the truncated icosahedron. The first known image and complete description of a truncated icosahedron is from a rediscovery by Piero della Francesca, in his 15th-century book De quinque corporibus regularibus, which included five of the Archimedean solids (the five truncations of the regular polyhedra). The same shape was depicted by Leonardo da Vinci, in his illustrations for Luca Pacioli's plagiarism of della Francesca's book in 1509. Although Albrecht Dürer omitted this shape from the other Archimedean solids listed in his 1525 book on polyhedra, Underweysung der Messung, a description of it was found in his posthumous papers, published in 1538. Johannes Kepler later rediscovered the complete list of the 13 Archimedean solids, including the truncated icosahedron, and included them in his 1609 book, Harmonices Mundi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is an e-mail kindly sent to me by Giorgio Strano, a curator at the museum:

Besides the usual "Tropicus Cancri", "AEquator", etc. the sundial contains the following sentences:

"Ad Latitudinem Graduum Quadragintatrium Minutorum Triginta" (For the latitude of 43° 30')
"Sol idem semper, [nec non (?)] semper currit et ue[rtit ('?)]" (The sun is always the same, [however ?] it always runs and [turns around ?])
"Non sic antiq[ui]s notus, nunc tempora monstro" (I show the time of today, not as it was known to the ancients [i.e. the dial shows equal, not unequal hours])
"Surgentem ostendo solem, ostendoq[ue] cadentem" (I show the rising and the setting Sun)

[ (?)] indates plausible integrations of a sentence where the words in the sundial are scratched away
[ ] indicates resolved Latin abbreviations

I hope this information is what you were looking for.

Best regards,

Giorgio Strano
Curator

Comment: Interesting.  I was expecting something religious rather than something explanatory.

Comment: Perhaps read out loud in the original Latin, each sentence has a unique alliteration, a poetic lilt. (?)

Answer (score 3):

From the [Museums in Florence site History of Science page](http://www.museumsinflorence.com/musei/History_of_Science_museum.html), referring to a pair of panels comprising the Horary Quadrant (see below for description) of the Buonsignori sundial:

> The front of this finely decorated quadrant carries (1) a brass disk with markings for days, months, and zodiac signs, and (2) a moon dial. There is a magnetic compass for orientation. On the back of the instrument are a shadow square, a degree scale, and a sundial with unequal hour lines set for latitude 43°30' (Florence). Made by Stefano Buonsignori, as 
>   indicated by the initials - D.STEP. B.F.F.- [Stefano Buonsignori Florentinus Fecit]. Provenance: Medici collections.

Presumably the mounted compass allows the user to correctly orient the sundial and thus read the applicable gnomon (the brass piece protruding from each panel used to cast a shadow).

Here, we are using the term [quadrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrant_(instrument)) to refer to an instrument used to measure angles up to ninety degrees.

The four different quadrants are :

- The sine quadrant, used for solving trigonometric problems and taking astronomical observations.
- The universal quadrant, used for solving astronomical problems for any latitude.
- The horary quadrant, used for finding the time with the sun.
- The astrolabe quandrant, a quadrant developed from the astrolabe used to represent the position of celestial bodies.

Comment: Fascinating. Still want to know what is written at the top of each facet.

Comment: @TomCopeland So do I, now I've seen it.  Really gorgeous instrument.

Comment: see also my contribution to this MO-Q http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32479/what-are-some-mathematical-sculptures/252321#252321 which motivates my interest in this particular polyhedral sundial among the examples at the museum.

Comment: @TomCopeland Nice stuff.  I'm sure you will have seen it, but the Rio Olympics cauldron is wonderfully hypnotic : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtoi2YhgnyI

Comment: yes it is. I hadn't seen it. You should add the spiral mobile to the MO-Q.

Answer (score 2):

From https://www.mhs.ox.ac.uk/epact/catalogue.php?ENumber=29766&Level=Detail, which has [an image showing two of the inscriptions](https://www.mhs.ox.ac.uk/epact/picturel.php?ENumber=29766):

> The dials are drawn for Italian hours with pin gnomons for latitude 43? 30' as is stated in an inscription on the north inclining face 'Ad latitudinem Graduum Quadragintarium Minutorum Triginta'....Three of the four reclining dials carry a motto in an horizontal band at the top of the dial. These are, 'Sol idem semper n{o}s [?] semper currit e [illegibile]'; 'Non sic antiqs notus numc tempora monstro'; 'Surgentem ostendo solem, ostendoq cad tez.' (Anthony J. Turner)

Comment: A much better image and more detail on locations of the inscriptions! All in agreement with Strano's e-mail.

Comment: Why don't you add the higher resolution image to your response?

Comment: @TomCopeland It's larger than a page, so if I resize it, you have to click on it to see the full image anyway. So I figured a link was good enough. You can add it if you want. BTW, I found the original (I presume): http://catalogue.museogalileo.it/images/cat/oggetti_944/7531_3123_1222-026_944.jpg

Comment: yes, that is the Museo Galileo from which I got my image after finding it on the MO user Bruno Vallette's academic website. I'll just let the link suffice to the better image. Thanks.